# ffmpeg - How to embed new audio and subtitle in video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to embed mp4 file to subtitle and new audio on once command.

I did only embed audio with this code:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -vcodec libx264 -vb 7000k -aspect 16:9 -s 1920x1080 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -y output.mp4
```

But I can't embed subtitle.
I think it needs changing -map code.
How can I do this?